# Appearances of apps' icons

Tags: android, icons, customization, launcher

Is it somehow possible to query the appearances of icons of apps? I want to know where exactly a user has placed an application (e.g. only in drawer or also on homescreen). I basically need to know this for all apps the user has installed. I looked into the API but could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The Launcher (which is an app) handles this. Since the user can have more than one at the same time and they can come from several places its not likely this information will be available or if it is reliable.